# Why Git's http-protocol only negotiate in terms of want-list and have-list?

Tags: git

From reading [pack-protocol doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-protocol) it seems Git's pack-protocol negotiate packfile in terms of shallow-line and depth-request in addition to want-list and have-list. But from reading [http-protocol doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/http-protocol) it seems that http-protocol (smart http) is not the same and only negotiate with want-list and have-list. **Why is there this discrepancy?** I thought only the transport is different. It is not the case that the http-protocol have to be stateless either as the server-client communication can span multiple requests/responses.

I guess if the client send enough have lines then the server can figure out what the client need regardless. Does that mean the http protocol simply can't handle shallow fetch?

Comment: This isn't quite right. There are dumb protocols and smart protocols. Http can use either one. The other transports are always smart. The pack protocol documentation describes the smart protocols.

Comment: @torek I'm only comparing the smart http-protocol against the pack-protocol. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: OK. I think the smart http pack protocol gets all the smart features, but I won't swear that this is the case; the guys who wrote these particular bits of documentation are more familiar with that part of Git than I am.